# Running vim's ':make' using ':term'

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, terminal-buffer, makeprg

Is there a way that I can have the `:make` command output itself to a terminal window in vim? In the 8.1 release, they added the `:term` command, which allows you to run an external program in a vim window. I was wondering if there's some way to combine the two.

I want this because i use vim-latex for compiling my .tex files (which compiles using `:make`), and it would actually be helpful for me to be able to deal with errors and stuff while still in vim.

Comment: "it would actually be helpful for me to be able to deal with errors and stuff while still in vim." Do you know that that quickfix list is populated with the output of `:make`? You can bring up the quickfix window via `:copen`. See `:h quickfix` for more information.

Comment: @PeterRincker tex has you deal with errors interactively

Comment: are you using `-interaction=nonstopmode`?  does vim-latex not set this by default?

Comment: Even though this is old: the answer to the comment of @mass is: vim-latex sets `-interaction=nonstopmode`. This can be checked with `:verbose set makeprg` which returns `makeprg=pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*
        Last set from ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/vim-latex/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim`. So the comment of Peter Rincker is also helpful.

Comment: @AGoldMan: Have you noticed [this paragraph](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/b523d676be8159405af15f35efc44e0eb305e74b/doc/latex-suite.txt#L1480-L1488) in the help file of vim-latex?

Answer (score 1):

On windows gvim only, you can use `set guioptions+=!` to run `make` in a terminal.  This isn't yet supported on other platforms so you will have to find an alternative.

If you want to create a new terminal each time,

```
command -nargs=* Make execute 'terminal' &makeprg.(empty(<q-args>)?'':' '.<q-args>)
```

Comment: Does your second suggestion still populate the quickfix list?

Comment: No, that would take some work.  I'm a bit confused whether you want interactivity like in the terminal or non-interactivity like in the quickfix.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for (using the terminal new vim 8.1 feature) but you should check asyncrun plugin which let you execute whatever you want asynchronously and get the output in quick fix (using errorformat to parse the output...). 
[asyncrun.vim](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `bash`-like shell, you can put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=? MakeInTerminal silent call s:MakeInTerminal(<q-args>)

function s:MakeInTerminal(args)
  const l:cmd = expandcmd(&makeprg) .. (a:args == '' ? '' : ' ' .. a:args)
  const l:options = {'term_name': '!' .. l:cmd}
  call term_start([&g:shell, &g:shellcmdflag, l:cmd], l:options)
endfunction
```

Then you can run `make` in a terminal with `:MakeInTerminal`. See also a [more complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216609/3352722).